# Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I keep getting this error message

> Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' to SecondViewController

I honestly have no clue please help

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     var destination = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
     destination.myString = outputName.text!
}
```

on the 'var' line but is now on the override 'func line' i have litterally no clue what it means.

Comment: it means that UITableViewController is not SecondViewController. you want to move to SecondViewController but moving to UITableViewController instead

Comment: @AndreyChernukha what?

Comment: is what I wrote really not understandable at all?

Comment: so i make the class in UItableview to match secondviewcontroller

Comment: show the declaration of your SecondViewController class

Comment: like the whole file

Comment: no, just class SecondViewController: part. I want to see if it derives from UITableViewController or not

Comment: class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

Comment: ok. it means that Sh_Khan answer won't work. The problem is worse. Your segue is connected to UITableViewController in the storyboard whereas you're trying to make SecondViewController out of it. You need to go to the storyboard and adjust the segue

Comment: so my segue goes from the 1st story board to the second is that wrong and do i have to add anything into the class

Comment: your segue can't go from one storyboard to another. This is impossible. Your segue just leads to a wrong view controller inside one storyboard .

Comment: go to the storyboard file. Find the segue. Connect it to SecondViewController not UITableViewController

Comment: i meant view controller

Comment: it says it is going to the second view controller

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController'  to 'skateapp.SecondViewController'

Comment: because in fact it is UITableViewController

Comment: You need to set the type of the controller in the storyboard

Comment: ohhhh i made the view controller a tableview controller can i not do that

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: it will be tedious to explain everything

Comment: fair enough i have to leave this till tomorrow but thanks for explaining my situation cause i had no clue much appreciated.

Comment: send me your project to andrey.chernukha.ios.developer@gmail.com and I will adjust that in a minute

Comment: but really, familiarize yourself with storyboards

Answer (score 1):

So i solved it! I had the class on the second ViewController punctuated wrong i forgot the capital S

Comment: can't until tomorrow @AndreyChernukha

Answer (score 0):

For this

```
var destination = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
```

to avoid crash you need to set class name `SecondViewController` to the destination vc in storyboard assuming

```
class SecondViewController:UITableViewController {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
```

I hope this will work.